# EVITAR EL RESETEO DE UNA CASILLA DEL FORMULARIO

Tags: javascript, html5

Hola tengo una pregunta y no se si es posible pero supongo que si.
Tengo un formulario y utilizo el método reset()

```
$("#frmUsuariosLaboratorio").each(function () {
           this.reset();
       });
```

y lo que quiero es que no me resetee un solo campo del formulario

```
 <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="row">
                           <form role="form" method="POST"  id="frmUsuariosLaboratorio">
                           <div class="col-md-5">
                                 <div class="box-body">

                                  <input type="text"   name="idusuario_L" id="idusuario_L" style="display:none"/>

                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label>Tipo registro *</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="tipo_registro_L" name="tipo_registro_L">
                    <option value="0">SELECCIONE UN TIPO</option>
                    <option value="nino">NIÑO</option>
                    <option value="adulto">ADULTO</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                   <div class="form-group" id="a">
                        <label for="documento_L">Documento *</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="documento_L" name="documento_L" placeholder="Ingrese el Documento del Participante">
                    </div>

                        <div class="form-group" id="b">
                        <label for="nombre_L">Nombres *</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_L" name="nombre_L" placeholder="Ingrese los Nombres del Participante">
                    </div>

                        <div class="form-group" id="c">
                         <label for="apellido_L">Apellidos *</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido_L" name="apellido_L" placeholder="Ingrese los Apellidos del Participante">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" id="d">
                        <label for="edad_L">Edad *</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edad_L" name="edad_L" placeholder="Ingrese la Edad del niño">
                    </div>
```

No quiero que me resetee el campo "seleccion de un tipo"

pero sin envargo voy a necesitar que se resetee en otros

Comment: Antes de resetear el formulario guarda el valor del select option, luego reseteas el formulario y por ultimo asigna el valor que guardaste previamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes controlar el evento reset del formulario, guardar el valor del campo que quieres y luego asignarlo, algo así:

```js
let tipoRegistroSeleccionado = '';

const asignarValoresPorDefecto = () => {
  document.querySelector("#tipo_registro_L").value = tipoRegistroSeleccionado;
}

const onResetFrmUsuariosLaboratorio = () => {
  -- Guardamos el valor que hayan selccionado en el tipo antes de limpiar el formulario
  tipoRegistroSeleccionado = document.querySelector("#tipo_registro_L").value;

  -- Pasado un tiempo asignamos los valores que guardamos
  setTimeout(asignarValoresPorDefecto, 100);
}

-- Controlamos el evento reset del formulario
document.querySelector("#frmUsuariosLaboratorio")
  .addEventListener("reset", onResetFrmUsuariosLaboratorio);
```

```html
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="row">
    <form role="form" method="POST" id="frmUsuariosLaboratorio">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="box-body">

          <input type="text" name="idusuario_L" id="idusuario_L" style="display:none" />

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Tipo registro *</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="tipo_registro_L" name="tipo_registro_L">
              <option value="0">SELECCIONE UN TIPO</option>
              <option value="nino">NIÑO</option>
              <option value="adulto">ADULTO</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" id="a">
            <label for="documento_L">Documento *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="documento_L" name="documento_L" placeholder="Ingrese el Documento del Participante">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" id="b">
            <label for="nombre_L">Nombres *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_L" name="nombre_L" placeholder="Ingrese los Nombres del Participante">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" id="c">
            <label for="apellido_L">Apellidos *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido_L" name="apellido_L" placeholder="Ingrese los Apellidos del Participante">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" id="d">
            <label for="edad_L">Edad *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edad_L" name="edad_L" placeholder="Ingrese la Edad del niño">
          </div>

          <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podría ser posible que en vez de que se active el reinicio del frm cuando le doy al boton reset se active,cuando cambie de tipo de registro es que el error que tengo es que hago una consulta por el rol de niño y luego quiero cambiar a el de adulto continua con los datos del niño y bise versa

Comment: Claro que puedes hacerlo, tendrías que controlar el evento onChange del select `tipo_registro_L` para limpiar los demás campos cuando se cambie de valor, pero esto que mencionas no es acorde a la pregunta inicial.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada, saludos.